# Suggesting to a commentor how to extend their statement in an answer

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

I'm far from lazy, but I do appreciate a good SE answer. A [comment on an answer to a question of mine](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/61056/7178) links to a Github repo of software that solves the question in the OP. I suggested to the commenter to post it as an answer.

Since a [good answer is more than just a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), I suggested to the commenter to include a code example that deals with the specific situation in the OP.

**Can this be considered as this lazy on my part as the OP, or am I helping the commenter to give a really good answer?**

Comment: Wouldn't this have been better to ask on [Meta UX](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I actually did first as on Meta UX, then immediately deleted the question to ask here as the question is not specific to Meta UX. In fact, I daily see link-only answers on Super User.

Comment: If the commentor wanted to give an answer he would have. Why bother him?

Comment: And if you want this question to be suitable to all sites I would change the title to *Telling a commentor to extend their statement in an answer* or so.

Comment: @juergend: I'm operating under the assumption that the comment would like to help the OP and to make the site more useful for those who look at older questions to find answers to their current problems.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the title with your suggestions, though not verbatim.

Comment: Just steal the comment and post it as an answer yourself, if the commenter wanted to they'd have posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Post the comment asking them to create a helpful answer - i.e. with code, link explanation, or whatever you see fit for a good answer. If they do so, success!

If not, if you think you can post a better answer, do so; success! If not, leave the slightly unhelpful answer and wait for someone to provide a better one; success!

```
Success: 3/3
Failure: 0/3
```

Comment: Emrakul: Could you please address the issue regarding the suggestion to include code and not just a link. Thank you.